# Installer for Python Executable on Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, cx-freeze

I'm trying to figure out a way to create an installer for a python application that I have created an executable for using cx freeze. I'd like to be similar to the windows standard installation wizard, but I would also like to be able to customize it as much as possible (removing windows, adding logos where the standard blue windows computer is, etc.).

The major requirments are:

- needs to be able to install .Net (and possibly other dependencies)
- needs to be able to add program to start-up processes
- look and feel (logos, banners, etc.) need to be able to be customized

I've tried Inno Setup, and while this gets my pretty close to what I want but does not give me some of the customization I need.

A good example of installation wizards I'm trying to replicate would be the ones for Firefox or Chrome.

I know that I can create a custom installation wizard for this sort of thing from scratch if needed. I just wasn't sure if something already existed for this, or if there was some utility that would allow me to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed a Python/GTK/OpenGL based desktop application in the past and in order create the executable and an installer I've used PyInstaller +  [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page).
NSIS is what you're asking for: it's quite flexible, you may want to give a try.

Comment: You might also want to look at [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). I get the impression it's not as flexible as NSIS, but it's quite easy to get started with.